# Extends Balanced BST into C++ STL Map

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, stl

I've implemented a balanced binary search tree (Red-black tree) for practice purposes. here is the header of data-structure of underlying nodes and methods I've implemented so far:

```
#ifndef BST_H
#define BST_H
template <typename T>
class treeNode {
public:
    treeNode *left;
    treeNode *right;
    T key;
    treeNode(T key)
        : key(key)
        , left(nullptr)
        , right(nullptr) {
    }
};

template <typename T>
class BST {
public:
    BST() {
        root = nullptr;
        nodes = 0;
    }

    BST(BST const& rhs);

    BST& operator = (BST rhs) {
        this->swap(rhs);
    }

    BST& operator = (BST&& rhs) {
        this->swap(rhs);
    }

    ~BST() {
        clear(root);
    }

    void swap(BST& other) {
        std::swap(root, other.root);
        std::swap(nodes, other.nodes);
    }

    void clear(treeNode<T>* node) {
        if(node) {
            if(node->left) clear(node->left);
            if(node->right) clear(node->right);
            delete node;
        }
    }

    bool isEmpty() const {
        return root == nullptr;
    }
    void inorder(treeNode<T>*);
    void traverseInorder();

    void preorder(treeNode<T>*);
    void traversePreorder();

    void postorder(treeNode<T>*);
    void traversePostorder();

    void insert(T const& );

    void remove(T const& );

    treeNode<T>* search(const T &);

    treeNode<T>* minHelper(treeNode<T>*);
    treeNode<T>* min();

    treeNode<T>* maxHelper(treeNode<T>*);
    treeNode<T>* max();

    size_t size() const;

    void sort();
    treeNode<T>* inOrderSuccessor(treeNode<T>*);
    bool isBST(treeNode<T>*) const;
    bool isBST() const;

private:
    treeNode<T> *root;
    size_t nodes;
};
#endif
```

I intend to implement C++ STL `map` (I've already implemented STL `unordered_map` using Hashtable) for which the underlying data-structure is Red-Black Tree AFAIK. How I can extend my tree to a key-value generic type map?

No need of any sort of source code. Some intuition will suffice. Thanks :)

Comment: extend the `treeNode` to take two template parameters for `key` and `value`, and the same for BST, the other is implement `map` using this class as helper and following the standard interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With intuition: `T` will probably be `pair<const key_type,mapped_type>`. I'm Assuming that currently you use `node.key < another_node.key` for comparisons. That will not do, because a map should be only using the first part of the pair for that. You could add a `Compare` functor as a template parameter (in similar manner as you'll have to for your `map` class) to your tree to make it useful for implementing a stl compatible map.

You may choose to design your tree so that key and value classes are separate rather than combined. Here's example code for the template definition:

```
template<class Key, class Value, class Comp=std::less<Key>>
class BST {
    Compare comp;
public:
    BST(const Comp& comp = Comp()): comp(comp)
//...

// usage
if(comp(node.key, another_node.key)) {
    // node is considered to be strictly before another_node
```

You can use `std::less` as a sensible default parameter for other users of the tree, but the map implementation should forward the comparator which was given for the map.

A fully stl compatible container should support custom allocators too and to make that possible, so must the internal tree structure.

Comment: +1 as I also thought something similar in my mind! But I think it would be better to have `template <typename Key_type, typename Value_type>` for node and `template <typename Key_type, typename Value_type, typename Comp = defaultComparator<K, V> >` for tree.

Comment: Yea, separating the key and value is probably good design choice. Not necessary when you have comparator, but cleaner.

Comment: @KaidulIslam about the comparator, it needs only the key as template parameter and could be defualted to `std::less<Key>`. I've added a mention that the tree should also support custom allocators.

Comment: Regarding `std::less<Key>`, now some code example will be helpful :) Please edit your answer!

Comment: @KaidulIslam I added some example code for the comparator.

Comment: Ops, `std::less<T>` and `std::greater<T>`... I totally forgot :P Thanks for your help! Hope everything would work!